# Java - How to add "\\" infront of "(" or ")" in a String

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I am reading a document and removing some words to it.
I have the following function:

```
 //Takes a string and removes the word
 private static String removeWord(String string, String word) {
    if (string.contains(word)) {
        String tempWord = word.trim();
        string = string.replaceAll(tempWord, "");
    }
    return string;
}
```

I have the following issue when I try to replace for example:

```
Hello world (
```

Gives me the following Error:

> Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 14

Doing some research I find out that is because of `split()` expects a regular expression, and brackets are used to mark capturing groups in a regex.

So I did this:

```
private static String removeWord(String string, String word) {
    if (string.contains(word)) {
        String [] temp = word.split(" ");
        word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i++) {
            if (temp[i].equals("(")){
                word += " "+ "\\(";
            }else if (temp[i].equals(")")){
                word += " "+ "\\)";
            } else {
                word += temp[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        String tempWord = word.trim();
        string = string.replaceAll(tempWord, "");
    }
    return string;
}
```

This code isn't the best solution. Because sometimes the string is like `(Hello world`.

How can I improve this part of the code?

Comment: just use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) before providing the string to the `.split` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to escape a regex manually. My advice is: Don't.

Even if you have successfully handled `()`, you still have a ton of other characters that have special meaning in regex to escape, such as `*+[]\?` just to name a few.

Luckily, there is a very convenient method called [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) that does this for you automatically:

```
 private static String removeWord(String string, String word) {
    if (string.contains(word)) {
        String tempWord = word.trim();
        string = string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(tempWord), "");
    }
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String removeWord(String string, String word) {
    return string.replaceFirst("\\W+" + word + "\\W+","");
}
```

\W matches a non word character [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
. You can also use replaceAll if you want to replace all occurrences, and if you want to replace a specific number of occurrences then you can use the replaceFirst in a loop.

Comment: Not working ``Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 14`` DEBUGG = ``\W+Hello wold (\W+``

Comment: Yes you need to escape to treat all special characters in word first. The idea is to show how \W can be used instead of splitting and looking for every char manually.